# JPanel drawing not wortking

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, draw

I am trying to draw a rectangle on a JFrame with a grid layout filled with JPanels.  However, the rectangle is being drawn under the JPanels, so I can see the color where the JPanels meet.  Is there a way to specify a bring to front sort of thing?

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestComponentAt extends JPanel {
   private static final int ROW_COUNT = 8;
   private static final int W = 60;
   private static final int H = W;
   private static final Dimension PREF_SIZE = new Dimension(W, H);
   private JFrame frame = new JFrame();

   public TestComponentAt() {
      setLayout(new GridLayout(ROW_COUNT, ROW_COUNT, 1, 1));
      setBackground(Color.black);
      for (int i = 0; i < ROW_COUNT * ROW_COUNT; i++) {
         JPanel panel = new JPanel();
         String name = String.format("[%d, %d]", 
               i / ROW_COUNT, i % ROW_COUNT);
         panel.setName(name);
         if ((i/ROW_COUNT) % 2 == (i%ROW_COUNT) % 2) {
            panel.setBackground(Color.black);
         }
         panel.setPreferredSize(PREF_SIZE);
         int row = i/ROW_COUNT;
         add(panel);
         if (panel.getBackground() == Color.black  &&  (row <= 2 || row >= 5)){
             repaint();
         }
      }
      addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            JPanel panel = (JPanel) getComponentAt(e.getPoint());
            if (panel == null || panel == TestComponentAt.this) {
               return;
            }
            if (panel != null) {
               panel.removeAll();
               panel.revalidate();
               panel.repaint();
            }
            panel.add(new JLabel(panel.getName()));
            panel.revalidate();
            panel.repaint();
         }
      });
   }
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        System.out.println("this has been called");
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.pink);
        g.fillOval(100, 100, 100, 100);
   }
   private void createAndShowGui() {
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setSize(480, 480);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new TestComponentAt());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       TestComponentAt obj = new TestComponentAt();
       obj.createAndShowGui();
   }
}
```

Comment: In other words, you've got some type of bug in code that you've not shown us. If you need help, if we're going to find out what you may be doing wrong, it would help immensely if you were to post your code, here, in your question as code-formatted text.

Comment: Also, please look at the [mcve] link which will tell you just what code we need to see.

Comment: OK -- what behaviors does the code that you've posted have that you don't want it to have, and what behaviors does it not have that it needs?

Comment: It should have a circle on top of all the JPanels, but instead it is showing below them.

Comment: I only see a black field with a circle in it. Is there more code not shown?

Comment: It should be a checker board with a circle.

Comment: Have you run the code above? For one thing, I have to use a mouse to expand the GUI to show anything, but then once I do that, I only see blackness with a pink circle.

Comment: `It should be a checker board with a circle` - then you need to draw your circle on the individual panel added to the grid, not the panel containing all the checkerboard panels.

Comment: Or else if floating above -- then perhaps on the glasspane or with a JLayer.

Comment: Did you try with the updated code, because I just copied it and ran it and it showed a checker board.

Answer (score 2):

A JLayer could be used to draw over the JPanel and its components. For example:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.LayerUI;

public class TestComponentAt extends JPanel {
    private static final int ROW_COUNT = 8;
    private static final int W = 60;
    private static final int H = W;
    private static final Dimension PREF_SIZE = new Dimension(W, H);
    private static final Color TRANSLUCENT_PINK = new Color(255, 175, 175, 200);

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public TestComponentAt() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(ROW_COUNT, ROW_COUNT, 1, 1));
        setBackground(Color.black);
        for (int i = 0; i < ROW_COUNT * ROW_COUNT; i++) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            String name = String.format("[%d, %d]", i / ROW_COUNT, i % ROW_COUNT);
            panel.setName(name);
            if ((i / ROW_COUNT) % 2 == (i % ROW_COUNT) % 2) {
                panel.setBackground(Color.black);
            }
            panel.setPreferredSize(PREF_SIZE);
            int row = i / ROW_COUNT;
            add(panel);
            if (panel.getBackground() == Color.black && (row <= 2 || row >= 5)) {
                frame.repaint();
            }
        }
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                JPanel panel = (JPanel) getComponentAt(e.getPoint());
                if (panel == null || panel == TestComponentAt.this) {
                    return;
                }
                if (panel != null) {
                    panel.removeAll();
                    panel.revalidate();
                    panel.repaint();
                }
                panel.add(new JLabel(panel.getName()));
                panel.revalidate();
                panel.repaint();
            }
        });

    }

    private class MyLayer extends LayerUI<JComponent> {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
            super.paint(g, c);
            g.setColor(TRANSLUCENT_PINK);
            g.fillOval(100, 100, 100, 100);
        }
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        TestComponentAt testComponentAt = new TestComponentAt();
        JLayer<JComponent> myLayer = new JLayer<JComponent>(testComponentAt, new MyLayer());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(480, 480);
        frame.getContentPane().add(myLayer);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestComponentAt obj = new TestComponentAt();
        obj.createAndShowGui();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Decorating Components Using JLayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) for more working examples. The tutorial will help explain what a JLayer can do. And you can keep a reference to the tutorial for more Swing basics.